# How can I create a custom session to use Unity Next and the Core Apps in 13.04?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, session

Is it possible to create a custom session that uses the [Unity Next UI](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unitynext/) instead of Unity 3D and along with it use the apps in the [Core Apps PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/+archive/daily) and [Non-Core apps PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/+archive/collection)?.

And possibly other new Touch oriented 3rd party apps?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you linked to a guide for how to build and run Unity Next, I will assume that you have already followed those instructions successfully and are stuck on the part about creating a custom login session available in the dropdown list at login.

This can be done by creating a new file in `/usr/share/xsessions`. First, encapsulate the startup commands in a new script (I'll assume you call this `/home/user/unity/unity-next-startup`):

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/user/unity/unity_build/build/libexec/unity-people-daemon
cd /home/user/unity/unity-next
./run
```

Then create a file in `/usr/share/xsessions`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Unity Next
Comment=Touch based environment from Ubuntu
Exec=/home/user/unity/unity-next-startup
TryExec=/home/user/unity/unity-next-startup
Type=XSession
```

When you log out, a new Unity Next option should be available at the login screen.

Comment: @bcbc Next time you can just click "improve" and remove the message at the bottom and then add a nice reason why in the edit reason ;) (See the revision history: http://askubuntu.com/posts/306505/revisions) New users sometimes think they need to mention that they've edited.