# run Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview on desktop?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-touch, emulation

Is there a way to run the Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview in an emulator or VirtualBox on 13.04 desktop? Id like to develop a cross-platform app but I do not have a device I can flash the touch preview too for editing.

Comment: To be able to build and run Unity Next you need to be using Ubuntu 13.10, then follow the instructions [here](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity8/) aftwards you have to install the SDK. You can install and create the touch apps (after installing the SDK) using Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04 but you can't run Unity Next on these releases. Having done that you might want to create a custom session if so, [read this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/304092/how-can-i-create-a-custom-session-to-use-unity-next-and-the-core-apps-in-13-04).

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Is there an Ubuntu Touch emulator or a way to install it in a VM?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259338/is-there-an-ubuntu-touch-emulator-or-a-way-to-install-it-in-a-vm)

Answer (score -1):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator
This shuld work to create an Ubuntu Touch emulator, it did for me

Good luck!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...